# MongoDB-Only Return Fields that are updated in the last hour/24 hours

Tags: linux, mongodb, database

I have searched many threads in this, but none of it seems to work.

The closest I got is form here:

```
db.<collection>.find({ $where: function () { return Date.now() - this._id.generation_time() < (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  }  })
```

But it gave me this error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "TypeError: Object edge:Package-****-34d7-4313-a4b9-13b5863fadf2 has no method 'generation_time' near 'this._id.generation_time() < (24 * 60 * ' ",
    "code" : 16722
```

It seems like something is wrong for this particular kind of data format.

One segment of the database:

```
  {
        "_id" : "edge:Package-1e63f289-022e-4678-b806-72244277db54",
        "data_1442611395145" : {
                "ulid" : ObjectId("55fc4883e1382301adfde5dd"),
                "etlp" : "AMBER",
                "api" : {
                        "indicators" : [
                                {
                                        "idref" : "CISCP:indicator-161e129e-3647-48fb-ab4c-ff1bea0e08a9"
                                }
                        ],
                        "timestamp" : "2015-09-18T17:23:15.145333+00:00",
                        "version" : "1.1.1",
                        "id" : "edge:Package-1e63f289-022e-4678-b806-72244277db54",
                        "stix_header" : {
                                "handling" : [
                                        {
                                                "controlled_structure" : "../../../../descendant-or-self::node()",
                                                "marking_structures" : [
                                                        {
                                                           "color" : "AMBER",
                                                           "xsi:type" : "tlpMarking:TLPMarkingStructureType"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                           "xsi:type" : "simpleMarking:SimpleMarkingStructureType",
                                                           "statement" : "FOUO"
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "hash" : ".cdb111212d2706be3dcb58b896cd1629993fa951",
                "idns" : "http://soltra.com/",
                "etou" : [ ],
                "esms" : [
                        "FOUO"
                ],
                "edges" : {
                        "CISCP:indicator-161e129e-3647-48fb-ab4c-ff1bea0e08a9" : "ind"
                },
                "summary" : {
                        "intent" : [ ]
                }
        },
        "created_on" : ISODate("2015-09-18T17:23:15.490Z"),
        "created_by_username" : "admin",
        "data" : {
                "ulid" : ObjectId("55fc4883e1382301adfde5dd"),
                "etlp" : "AMBER",
                "api" : {
                        "indicators" : [
                                {
                                        "idref" : "CISCP:indicator-161e129e-3647-48fb-ab4c-ff1bea0e08a9"
                                }
                        ],
                        "timestamp" : "2015-09-18T17:23:15.145333+00:00",
                        "version" : "1.1.1",
                        "id" : "edge:Package-1e63f289-022e-4678-b806-72244277db54",
                        "stix_header" : {
                                "handling" : [
                                        {
                                                "controlled_structure" : "../../../../descendant-or-self::node()",
                                                "marking_structures" : [
                                                        {
                                                           "color" : "AMBER",
                                                           "xsi:type" : "tlpMarking:TLPMarkingStructureType"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                           "xsi:type" : "simpleMarking:SimpleMarkingStructureType",
                                                           "statement" : "FOUO"
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "hash" : "c45722264e9d129154c2b01ad9e0709e836e2fe8",
                "idns" : "http://soltra.com/",
                "etou" : [ ],
                "esms" : [
                        "FOUO"
                ],
                "edges" : {
                        "CISCP:indicator-161e129e-3647-48fb-ab4c-ff1bea0e08a9" : "ind"
                },
                "summary" : {
                        "intent" : [ ]
                }
        },
        "cv" : "1442611395145",
        "versions" : [
                "1442611395145"
        ],
        "created_by" : ObjectId("559450775bf8065a2d6476c1"),
        "tg" : [ ],
        "type" : "pkg",
        "created_by_organization" : null
}
{
        "_id" : "CISCP:indicator-161e129e-3647-48fb-ab4c-ff1bea0e08a9",
        "created_on" : ISODate("2015-09-18T17:23:15.491Z"),}
```

I wonder if there's a way for me to use the "timestamp" to compare with the Date.now().....Tried a few things already didn't work... Wonder if any GURU can lend a hand?

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `_id`'s **[timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/)** (which will fail because it's not a valid **[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#core-object-id-class)**), do a date range query on the `"created_on"` date field by creating a variable that holds a date object 24 hours ago and use the **[`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/)** operator in your query:

```
var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
db.collection.find({ "created_on": { "$gte": yesterday } });
```

Comment: Hello! Tried your script in a test.js and then did a mongo localhost:27017/** test.js. It only has a message: connecting to : <db>.

Comment: Can you try to run the query in mongo shell against the actual collection name?